# MySQL view to CSV file using Java, Spring, and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, orm

I've been asked to output a CSV file from a view in MySQL.  The app I currently am writing uses Spring and Hibernate to create the database, but the view is just handed to me.

Hibernate doesn't know anything about this view, but I'd want to do something like this:

```
public List<Object> getCsvView() {
  return (List<Object>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from myView");
}
```

My guess was that I could map a native query so that hibernate knows about the view.  This got a little tricky when I read the docs:

> You can also map a native query[...]To
>   achieve that, you need to describe the
>   SQL resultset structure using
>   @SqlResultSetMapping[...].

Now, I'm really not interested in mapping the structure of the result.  I'm happy to have the structure just be a bunch of objects.

Furthermore they might change this view at any time.  I'm really not thrilled about my app even knowing about the view.

So, is there an easy way to do this in the Spring/Hibernate world, or am I attacking this problem the hard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform a native query on the view and you'll get a `List` of `Object[]` with scalar values for each column as result. From the documentation:

> #### [16.1.1. Scalar queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646)
>
> The most basic SQL query is to get a
>   list of scalars (values).
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS").list();
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS").list();
> ```
>
> These will return a List of Object
>   arrays (`Object[]`) with scalar values
>   for each column in the CATS table.
>   Hibernate will use `ResultSetMetadata`
>   to deduce the actual order and types
>   of the returned scalar values.
>
> To avoid the overhead of using
>   `ResultSetMetadata`, or simply to be
>   more explicit in what is returned, one
>   can use `addScalar()`:
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS")
>  .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG)
>  .addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING)
>  .addScalar("BIRTHDATE", Hibernate.DATE)
> ```
>
> This query specified:
>
> - the SQL query string
> - the columns and types to return
>
> This will return Object arrays, but
>   now it will not use
>   `ResultSetMetadata` but will instead
>   explicitly get the ID, NAME and
>   BIRTHDATE column as respectively a
>   Long, String and a Short from the
>   underlying resultset. This also means
>   that only these three columns will be
>   returned, even though the query is
>   using * and could return more than the
>   three listed columns.
>
> It is possible to leave out the type
>   information for all or some of the
>   scalars.
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS")
>  .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG)
>  .addScalar("NAME")
>  .addScalar("BIRTHDATE")
> ```
>
> This is essentially the same query as
>   before, but now `ResultSetMetaData` is
>   used to determine the type of NAME and
>   BIRTHDATE, where as the type of ID is
>   explicitly specified.
>
> How the `java.sql.Types` returned from
>   `ResultSetMetaData` is mapped to
>   Hibernate types is controlled by the
>   Dialect. If a specific type is not
>   mapped, or does not result in the
>   expected type, it is possible to
>   customize it via calls to
>   `registerHibernateType` in the
>   `Dialect`.

Looks perfect to generate a CVS file without knowing anything about the view :)

Comment: Interesting.  I agree this looks just like what I would need.  Is there a kosher way to get the session out of "getHibernateTemplate()"?

Comment: I can just inject the session into that dao impl.  I was just checking to see if there is a tricky way of doing this same thing with the HibernateTemplate.  Perhaps hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();?

Comment: @Stephano: Personally, I don't use the HibernateTemplate, I prefer [Template-less DAOs](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/). But check `HibernateTemplate#executeFind`.

Comment: excellent.  that acutally worked up through the query.  hibernate calls "select * from myView" but barfs on "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1" :(

Comment: I noticed that there are some LONGTEXT fields in the view.  I think I am running into this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986094/jpa-native-query-for-longtext-field-in-a-mysql-view-results-in-error

Comment: @Stephano: Solution posted in the mentioned question.

Comment: Awesome.  Well, it was a long trip around the block all for a little library update.  Still, I learned something and had some beers, so no complaints here.